# How to extract a small portion of PDF as PDF?

Tags: pdf, latex, print-to-pdf

I wonder if there is a method that allows me to select a smaller portion (like a table from an article) and save it as another PDF file so I can put it into my presentation, and I can scale it without quality loss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of applications which allow you to achieve this. Some of them are:

- LibreOffice 5 (free - Windows, Mac, Linux)

> Thanks to LibreOffice's built-in Draw feature. In Draw, your PDF
>   documents temporarily become images that can be edited. When you're
>   finished, the document simply needs to be exported back into PDF
>   format. This feature works the same on all platforms, which means you
>   can edit PDF documents on Windows, Mac, and Linux in the same way.

Basically, once you have installed LibreOffice, you can open any PDF file with it (usually with LibreOffice Draw or LibreOffice Writer in the case oh Hybrid PDFs, but LibreOffice automatically detects this and chooses the best application on a per-file basis). Within Draw, you can select, crop and modify portions of the document and export it back to PDF.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

- PDF Architect (free version with limited functionality - Windows only)

> PDF Architect's powerful Edit Module allows you to make modifications
>   directly within your PDF file without the need to export it or copy
>   the content to another format.

PDF Architect allows you a more fine-grained selection of the elements in a PDF File, as well as many other useful features (merging of PDFs, forms, etc.) but it is only available in Windows.

[image: Screenshot]

There are many others, but these two should give you a starting point. You can use any of them to export portions of a PDF file also in PDF or other formats.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Comment: @bwDraco Thanks a lot for the hint. I provided more information about both applications (which I personally use) - Hope its better now :-)

Comment: Thanks! I will try these and let you know. I hope it's OK to wait a while (before I accept) for possible alternatives?

Comment: Of course, and only accept the answer if the suggested solution suits your needs :-)